# UV map lost its mesh after painting it

Tags: uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I am new to UV unwrapping and I was hoping someone could help me out.  Here is what I did.

I used smartuv unwrapping and got a decent uv map.  I then edited the map to remove overlapping vertices.  I then used the pack islands feature and changed the margin to 0.02 so that I would not get bleeding between islands while I was painting.  Everything looked good up until this point.

I then decided to paint the entire UV map black and then paint my model white to reset the image.  This made the uv map you see below.  Now all you can see is the black background and my white model. I can't see or click on any vertices to edit them, which is necessary because the pack islands feature moved some vertices way over to the other side of the image creating new overlaps.  So I guess my question is, how do I bring back the vertices and lines of the mesh in the uv map so that I can move them around and edit them?  I really don't want to start over as it took me forever to get rid of all overlaps.  Thanks so much for the help!

[image]

Here is the same map in edit mode
[image]

[image]

Comment: At first glimpse, it doesn't look like you are in edit, but we need some info about that

Comment: You are right.  I wasn't in edit mode in the picture that I attached.  However when I enter edit mode by hitting the Tab key the uv looks exactly the same.  I get the bar along the top that lets me select between vertices, edges, and faces, as well as everything else but there is no mesh to edit.

Comment: Ok, I have made some progress.  If I click the two arrow UV sync selection I can get the mesh to show up again.  However when I then go to move the vertices stretched across the map some of them are linked together somehow even though they are in different island and they all move at once which does not help.  I read to deselect UV sync selection so that I can move one vertex at a time but if I do that everything disappears.

Comment: They do that because they are probably merge on the mesh, you could use face selection instead of vertex selection to move per face

Comment: Face selection doesn't seem to select anything on these particular faces.  On the two pictures posted you can see a diagonal line.  At the bottom of this line is a vertex that needs to be moved to the top left of the screen.  I don't understand how face select will help.  Is there any way to deselect UV sync selection and keep the mesh visible?  Thanks so much for the help.  I am sure helping noobs like me is a pain but I really appreciate it.

Comment: I should mention that before this problem occurred it did not seem like any vertices were linked together like this.  I was moving a bunch of them around independently.

Comment: I figured it out.  If UV sync is not selected you can only see the vertices selected in the actual model in the 3D View in Edit Mode.